# jQuery .fadeTo() -- Fade back in after fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal with this project is to have a div that, when hovered over, picks a random background color and then fades out. However, I want to be able to go back and hover again over the div and have the process start over again. So far, I've only managed to get the random color and have it fade out, but when I mouse over to hover again, nothing happens. Tried removing the opacity and background classes to no avail. Here's my code so far:

```
$(function() {


    var $foo = $('.foo');

    function getRandomColor() {

        $foo.removeClass('background-color');
        $foo.addClass('opacity', '1');
        var length = 6;
        var chars = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var hex = '#';
        while(length--) hex += chars[(Math.random() * 16) | 0];
        return hex;
        }


    $foo.mouseenter(function(){

        $(this).css('background-color', getRandomColor());


        });

    $foo.mouseleave(function(){

        $(this).fadeTo( 1000, 0 );

        });


    });
```

HTML - Just a bunch of divs to test

```
<div class="foo box">Hello world</div>
<div class="foo box">Hello world</div>
<div class="foo box">Hello world</div>
<div class="foo box">Hello world</div>
<div class="foo box">Hello world</div>
<div class="foo box">Hello world</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you chain jQuery methods, and for going to 0 opacity and back, use `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` instead, along with a callback to reset the background color. Like so.

```
$(this).fadeOut(1000, function() { 
    $(this).css("background-color","transparent")
}); 
$(this).fadeIn(1000);
```

The `fadeOut` has the effect of fading to 0 opacity, in this case during 1 second. `fadeIn` does the opposite, the callback resets the color. If you do not want a color reset, do just this instead.

```
$(this).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kb4bvbyy/30/). Notice, that I removed the unneccessary class assignments, as you **can not** affect styling properties via classes, as you've tried to do.

Comment: This is almost perfect, but when the div fades back in the bg-color stays for a split second before becoming transparent. Fixed it like this: `$(this).fadeOut(1000, function() { $(this).css("background-color","transparent")}); $(this).fadeIn(1000); ` Thank you!

Comment: Thank's for the update, edited my answer and fiddle to include that.

Answer (score 2):

Try substituting `.css()` for `.removeClass()` , `.addClass()`

```
$foo.css('background-color', "");
$foo.css('opacity', '1');
```

for

```
$foo.removeClass('background-color');
$foo.addClass('opacity', '1');
```

---

```js
$(function() {

  var $foo = $('.foo');

  function getRandomColor() {

    $foo.css("background-color", "");
    $foo.css("opacity", '1');
    var length = 6;
    var chars = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var hex = '#';
    while (length--) hex += chars[(Math.random() * 16) | 0];
    return hex;
  }

  $foo.mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', getRandomColor());
  });

  $foo.mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(1000, 0);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="foo box">Hello world</div>
<div class="foo box">Hello world</div>
<div class="foo box">Hello world</div>
<div class="foo box">Hello world</div>
<div class="foo box">Hello world</div>
<div class="foo box">Hello world</div>
```