# jQuery function to reverse onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone help me understand this better. I'm simply fading out the box element in the DOM when the button is clicked by using the onclick.

Is there a simple way to cause the box to fade back in when the same button is clicked again?

```js
function fade() {
 $("#box").fadeOut();
};
```

```html
    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px; opacity: 1;"></div>

<button id="button3" onclick="fade();">Fade</button>
```

Comment: `fadeToggle()`?

Comment: Are you specifically interested in fades? or the general concept of toggling some effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggle the fading function:

```
$("#box").fadeToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to use toggle :

```
function fade() {
    $("#box").fadeToggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fadeToggle()

```js
function fade(){
 $('#box').fadeToggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px; opacity: 1;"></div>

<button id="button3" onclick="fade();">Fade</button>
```

Comment: it is a `div` element so it it is a displayed block by default

Comment: I was going to delete that part, didn't know it was under code example still. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use `fadeToggle()` instead of `fadeOut()`
full reference here: http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly make use of the 'is(":visible")' to check display status on the FadeOut and do the FadeIn instead.

```
function fade() {
    var mybox = $("#box");
    if (mybox.is(":visible"))
        mybox.fadeOut();
    else mybox.fadeIn();
};
```

Check out the [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ayuagrawal/zz88eu1x/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( function() {
      x=1;    
  } );
  function fade() {
        if(x==1){
       $("#box").fadeOut(1000) && (x=0);
      }
      else $("#box").fadeIn(1000) && (x=1);       
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px; opacity: 1;"></div>

<button id="button3" onclick="fade()">Fade</button>
```

please refer the link: [jQuery .fadeTo() -- Fade back in after fade out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687763/jquery-fadeto-fade-back-in-after-fade-out) for another example related to this.